# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle table

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

How do you migrate an empty field type to text in Room ?

Right now I'm facing this issue :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle data_table
>
> Expected: TableInfo{name='data_table', columns=
> url=Column{name='url', **type='TEXT'**, notNull=false,
> primaryKeyPosition=0}.....
>
> Found: TableInfo{name='data_table', columns= url=Column{name='url',
> **type=''**, notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}.....

I've tried using the UNDEFINED typeAffinity, but that has no effect.

Comment: What does your `@Entity` POJO have? Room really prefers types, and I haven't tried `UNDEFINED` -- is there a particular reason you are trying to avoid a type here?

Comment: The POJO field is a String. We have some legacy code that created the column without a data type.

Comment: Migrating pre-Room databases to Room will run into this sort of thing. Other than doing your own manual migration first, before starting to apply Room, I have no idea how to address this.

Comment: I ended up creating a new DB during migration and copying all the old data into the new one. This is inefficient when working with large DBs but I guess there's no choice at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is when creating the table, the creator did't indicate the column explicitly.**
There are two ways to be chosen to solve the problem.

1. You can create a new DB during migration and copy all the old data into the new one. Like this.

   ```
   static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
       @Override
       public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
           // Create the new table
           database.execSQL(
                   "CREATE TABLE data_table_new (url TEXT");
           // Copy the data
           database.execSQL(
                   "INSERT INTO data_table_new url SELECT url FROM data_table");
           // Remove the old table
           database.execSQL("DROP TABLE data_table");
           // Change the table name to the correct one
           database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE data_table_new RENAME TO data_table");
       }
   };
   ```

But it is inefficient when working with large db. So I use the second way.

2 You migrate the table to new table with explicit column type with your favourite db manager or terminal. Then put the new db into your project.