java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle
After updating the application to the new version it crashes with error
Expected:

TableInfo{name='promotion_entity', columns={actionTitle=Column{name='actionTitle', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, actionUri=Column{name='actionUri', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, type=Column{name='type', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, countryId=Column{name='countryId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2, defaultValue='undefined'}, enabled=Column{name='enabled', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, promoCodeResource=Column{name='promoCodeResource', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, imageMain=Column{name='imageMain', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, promoCodeType=Column{name='promoCodeType', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, sellerId=Column{name='sellerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, price_currencySign=Column{name='price_currencySign', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, terms=Column{name='terms', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, promoCode=Column{name='promoCode', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, userLimit=Column{name='userLimit', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, price_currency=Column{name='price_currency', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, updatedAt=Column{name='updatedAt', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, image=Column{name='image', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, publishedAt=Column{name='publishedAt', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, stores=Column{name='stores', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, price_amount=Column{name='price_amount', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, expiresAt=Column{name='expiresAt', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, timeLimit=Column{name='timeLimit', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, topOrder=Column{name='topOrder', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, activationCode=Column{name='activationCode', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, segmentIds=Column{name='segmentIds', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
                                                                                                 
Found:
???

I am using both manual and auto migration and test is passing successfully
@Test
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun testLatestMigration() {
    helper.createDatabase(MyDatabase.DATABASE_NAME, DB_OLD_VERSION).close()
    helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(
        MyDatabase.DATABASE_NAME,
        DB_VERSION,
        true,
    )
}

Why there is no "Found" TableInfo?
P.s I am adding migrations related to this table
private val MIGRATION_3_4 = object : Migration(3, 4) {
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    database.execSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE ${MyEntity.TABLE_NAME}")
    database.execSQL(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${MyEntity.TABLE_NAME} (" +
            "`id` INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "`countryId` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "`title` TEXT," +
            "`description` TEXT, " +
            "`type` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "`promoCodeResource` INTEGER," +
            "`image` TEXT, " +
            "`userLimit` INTEGER," +
            "`timeLimit` INTEGER," +
            "`promoCode` TEXT, " +
            "`actionUri` TEXT," +
            "`actionTitle` TEXT, " +
            "`segmentIds` TEXT," +
            "`stores` TEXT," +
            "`sellerId` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "`topOrder` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "`enabled` INTEGER," +
            "`publishedAt` TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "`expiresAt` TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "`updatedAt` TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "`activationCode` INTEGER, " +
            "`seller_sellerSellerId` INTEGER," +
            "`seller_sellerName` TEXT, " +
            "`seller_sellerLogo` TEXT," +
            "`price_amount` REAL, " +
            "`price_currency` TEXT," +
            "`price_currencySign` TEXT, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY(`id`, `countryId`))"
    )
    database.execSQL(
        "UPDATE ${UserEntity.TABLE_NAME} " +
        "SET promoHash = null " +
        "WHERE `id` = (SELECT userId FROM session_entity LIMIT 1)",
    )
    database.execSQL("COMMIT;")
}

And last migration related to MyEntity:
internal val MIGRATION_11_12 = object : Migration(11, 12) {
override fun migrate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    with(db) {
        execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE ${MyEntity.TABLE_NAME} " +
            "ADD COLUMN terms TEXT DEFAULT NULL",
        )
        execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE ${MyEntity.TABLE_NAME} " +
            "ADD COLUMN imageMain TEXT DEFAULT NULL",
        )
        execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seller_data_entity` (" +
                "`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `logo` " +
                "TEXT NOT NULL, `color` TEXT NOT NULL, `enabled` INTEGER " +
                "NOT NULL, `updatedAt` TEXT NOT NULL, `createdAt` TEXT NOT" +
                " NULL, `enabledAt` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))",
        )
        execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE ${CardEntity.TABLE_NAME} " +
            "ADD COLUMN `iconColor` TEXT DEFAULT NULL;",
        )
        execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE ${CardEntity.TABLE_NAME} " +
            "ADD COLUMN `iconCode` TEXT DEFAULT NULL;",
        )
    }
}

}
What is wrong with these migrations?

What are you even talking about, where is the migration? The error message is also truncated. This is not only lacking sufficient details, but it's also a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769772

@MartinZeitler, my question was about why I don't see Founded Table info and what might cause such an error. In the link you passed and in all other related questions, you can see Expected and Found table info, which is very useful as I could understand what column or structure is causing this, but in my case, I see nothing.

Changing default or null values of an empty table is something else than changing it, when it has record-sets, which may contain conflicting data... however, when it cannot find anything, it may be the table itself; else it should list the table-info. I really don't know, that's just an educated guess.

One can also conditionally drop: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...while you'd have to test them all in a row, to see where it bugs out: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions?hl=en#all-migrations-test

@MartinZeitler Thank you for pointing to test all migrations, it gave me the idea that the issue was a conflict between auto and manual migration from same DB version,

The issue was caused by having both a manual migration and an AutoMigration for the same version range (e.g., from = 11 to = 12). Room doesn’t allow overlapping migrations, which caused a conflict. Removing one of the migrations resolved the issue.
